# read-only properties in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, readonly

Is there a way to make a read-only property of an object in PHP? I have an object with a couple arrays in it. I want to access them as I normally would an array

```
echo $objObject->arrArray[0];
```

But I don't want to be able to write to those arrays after they're constructed. It feels like a PITA to construct a local variable:

```
$arrArray = $objObject->getArray1();
echo $arrArray[0];
```

And anyways, while it keeps the array in the object pristine, it doesn't prevent me from re-writing the local array variable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, the question is where do you want to prevent writing from?

The first step is making the array protected or private to prevent writing from outside of the object scope:

```
protected $arrArray = array();
```

If from "outside" of the array, a GETTER will do you fine.  Either:

```
public function getArray() { return $this->arrArray; }
```

And accessing it like

```
$array = $obj->getArray();
```

or

```
public function __get($name) {
    return isset($this->$name) ? $this->$name : null;
}
```

And accessing it like:

```
$array = $obj->arrArray;
```

Notice that they don't return references.  So you cannot change the original array from outside the scope of the object.  You can change the array itself...

If you really need a fully immutable array, you could use a Object using [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)...

Or, you could simply extend [`ArrayObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) and overwrite all of the writing methods:

```
class ImmutableArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
    public function append($value) {
        throw new LogicException('Attempting to write to an immutable array');
    }
    public function exchangeArray($input) {
        throw new LogicException('Attempting to write to an immutable array');
    }
    public function offsetSet($index, $newval) {
        throw new LogicException('Attempting to write to an immutable array');
    }
    public function offsetUnset($index) {
        throw new LogicException('Attempting to write to an immutable array');
    }
}
```

Then, simply make `$this->arrArray` an instance of the object:

```
public function __construct(array $input) {
    $this->arrArray = new ImmutableArrayObject($input);
}
```

It still supports most array like usages:

```
count($this->arrArray);
echo $this->arrArray[0];
foreach ($this->arrArray as $key => $value) {}
```

But if you try to write to it, you'll get a `LogicException`...

Oh, but realize that if you need to write to it, all you need to do (within the object) is do:

```
$newArray = $this->arrArray->getArrayCopy();
//Edit array here
$this->arrArray = new ImmutableArrayObject($newArray);
```

Comment: If I want to have my Immutable Array load itself with data on creation I would overwrite the __construct function, call the parent constructor, but how do I set what the object contains?

Comment: Very good answer! But notice that an array can contain objects: Every object is returned as a reference and can be changed, even with your immutable class: `$a = new ImmutableArrayObject( (object) ['foo' => 'bar'] ); $b = $a[0]; $b->foo = 'changed';`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PHP 5+ you can do it with __set() and [__get()](http://www.php.net/__get) methods.

You have to define how they work but should do just this.

Edit an example would be like this.

```
class Example {
    private $var;
    public function __get($v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach () {
                // handle it here
            }
        } else {
            return $this->$v;
        }
    }
}
```

This might not be the "best" way of doing it but it'll work depending on what you need

Comment: Boss:  "I thought you said you finished your algorithm" Client: "I did boss, what is the problem" Boss: "it does not work"  Client: "it works depending on what you need"

Comment: @Chris why is the client taking orders from the boss? Lol.

Answer (score 4):

If defined, the magic functions `__get()` and `__set()` will be called whenever a non-existing or private property is accessed. This can be used to create "get" and "set" methods for private properties, and for instance make them read-only or manipulate the data when stored or retrieved in it.

For instance:

```
class Foo
{
  private $bar = 0;
  public $baz = 4; // Public properties will not be affected by __get() or __set()
  public function __get($name)
  {
    if($name == 'bar')
      return $this->bar;
    else
      return null;
  }
  public function __set($name, $value)
  {
    // ignore, since Foo::bar is read-only
  }
}

$myobj = new Foo();
echo $foo->bar; // Output is "0"
$foo->bar = 5;
echo $foo->bar; // Output is still "0", since the variable is read-only
```

See also the [manual page for overloading in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Comment: I would recommend throwing an exception in `set` if you're not allowing a particular variable to be set.  The reason is that otherwise it can be quite confusing when someone new needs to do something, and it's not working.  "But I set that array to include this variable.  The assignment succeeds, so why the *#@$ isn't it working?"...

Answer (score 3):

For PHP 8.1+, you can use readonly properties:

```php
class Test
{
    public readonly array $arrArray;

    public function __construct()
    {
          $this->arrArray = [1, 2, 3];
    } 
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test->arrArray); // OK
$test->arrArray = [4, 5, 6]; // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

in the class, do this:

```
private $array;

function set_array($value) {
    $this->array = $value;
}
```

then you just set like this:

```
$obj->set_array($new_array);
```